# Appending value to a list depending on the JSON response

Tags: python, json, pandas, rest, http

I'm calling an API and I get the following response:

```
"items": [
                    {
                        "packagingType": "PCS",
                        "description": "[REDACTED]",
                        "productCode": "MATT",
                        "freightClass": "300",
                        "insuranceValue": 428.70999999971326,
                        "primaryReferenceNumber": null,
                        "poNumber": "[REDACTED]",
                        "skuNumber": "[REDACTED]",
                        "pluNumber": null,
                        "actualQuantity": 1,
                        "actualWeight": 125,
                        "actualWeightUnitOfMeasure": "Pounds",
                        "actualPallets": 1,
                        "actualVolume": null,
                        "actualVolumeUnitOfMeasure": "Cubic Feet",
                        "actualPackagingLength": null,
                        "actualPackagingHeight": null,
                        "actualPackagingWidth": null,
                        "actualPackagingUnitOfMeasure": "Inches",
                        "referenceNumbers": [
                            {
                                "type": "CustomerItemIdentifier1",
                                "value": "[REDACTED]"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "OrderItemId",
                                "value": "123456789"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "SHID",
                                "value": "[REDACTED]"
                            }
                        ],
                        "associatedStop": {
                            "pickSequenceNumber": null,
                            "dropSequenceNumber": null
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

But sometimes the API also sends an answer like this:

```
"items": [
                    {
                        "packagingType": "PCS",
                        "description": "[REDACTED]",
                        "productCode": "MISC",
                        "freightClass": "300",
                        "insuranceValue": 2500,
                        "primaryReferenceNumber": null,
                        "poNumber": "[REDACTED]",
                        "skuNumber": "[REDACTED]",
                        "pluNumber": null,
                        "actualQuantity": 1,
                        "actualWeight": 132,
                        "actualWeightUnitOfMeasure": "Pounds",
                        "actualPallets": null,
                        "actualVolume": null,
                        "actualVolumeUnitOfMeasure": "Cubic Feet",
                        "actualPackagingLength": null,
                        "actualPackagingHeight": null,
                        "actualPackagingWidth": null,
                        "actualPackagingUnitOfMeasure": "Inches",
                        "referenceNumbers": [
                            {
                                "type": "OrderItemId",
                                "value": "987654321"
                            }
                        ],
                        "associatedStop": {
                            "pickSequenceNumber": null,
                            "dropSequenceNumber": null
                        }
                    }
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to append the "value" under the "referenceNumbers" when the "type" is equal to "OrderItemId".

Can anyone please point me out on the right direction to do it?

UPDATE: This is my current block of code:

```
 for object in parsed['results']:
            if  object['event']['eventType'] in event_list:
                for item in object['event']['items']:
                    orders_event_name.append(object['event']['eventType'])
                    orders_customer_order.append(object['billToReferenceNumber'])
                    orders_reference_number.append(item['referenceNumbers']['value'])
                    orders_event_id.append(None)
                    orders_item_id.append(item['skuNumber'])
                    orders_datetime_started.append(object['eventTime'])
                    orders_seconds.append(None)
                    orders_load_number.append(object['event']['loadNumber'])
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: _Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to append the "value"_ What exactly do you mean?  Do you want to append something onto the value, or do you want to append the value onto some other variable?

Comment: @JohnGordon Append to other variable. When I said "value" I meant the field in the JSON response called "value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li = []
for resp in [response1, response2]:
    for i in resp['items'][0]['referenceNumbers']:
        if i['type'] == 'OrderItemId':
            li.append(i['value'])

li
```

Output:

```
['123456789', '987654321']
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An answer with your code:

```
for i in data:
    if i["referenceNumbers"][0]["type"] == "OrderItemId":
        orders_reference_number.append(i["referenceNumbers"][0]["value"])
        orders_event_id.append(None)
        orders_item_id.append(i['skuNumber'])

    else:
        print("Not OrderItemId")
```